# Entity Framework without Transaction?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, triggers

Is there a way to use EF without transaction? I have very simple single insert and don't want to roll-back when something goes wrong as there may be a trigger logging then raising error from the DB side which I have no control over. I just want to insert then catch any exceptions but don't want to roll-back.

Answer (score 3):

We are not aware of any way to get rid of transactions in Entity Framework CUD operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
using( var transation = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress) )
{
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This still executes in a transaction that EF opens.