# Entity Framework 5 without transactions

Tags: entity-framework, mysql-connector

I want to set entity framework so that SavesChanges() doesn't wrap all its generated SQL with a BEGIN and a COMMIT. I came across this suggestion from a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921467/entity-framework-without-transaction):

```
using( var transation = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress) )
{
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But that doesn't work for me. We are using the MYSQL connector, so I did do some digging by stepping through the source code of that, and I found EntityFramework is the one that is asking for a new transaction to be created, and not the fault of the connector see the following stack trace.
[image: MySQL stack trace]

Next I started looking through EF's source code (EF 6 is open source, and the relevant code looks the same in the decompiler)

```
        var needLocalTransaction = false;
        var connection = (EntityConnection)Connection;
        if (connection.CurrentTransaction == null
            && !connection.EnlistedInUserTransaction
            && _lastTransaction == null)
        {
            needLocalTransaction = startLocalTransaction;
        }

        ...


        if (needLocalTransaction)
        {
            localTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        }
```

Okay, so it looks if a transaction doesn't exist it creates one itself. And stepping further to how the current transaction is set up in EF I get to the code where EF sets up the connection

```
            var currentTransaction = Transaction.Current;

            EnsureContextIsEnlistedInCurrentTransaction(
                currentTransaction,
                () =>
                {
                    Connection.Open();
                    _openedConnection = true;
                    _connectionRequestCount++;
                    return true;
                },
                false);
```

And this seems to be the only place where the "TransactionScopeOption.Suppress" line comes in to play, however all that does is set the ambient transaction (Transaction.Current) to null. Forcing EF not to see a transaction and doing the opposite of what I want and creating a new transaction.

Has anyone else had any luck with turning off transaction in EF 5, or is my only solution to hack and build my own version of the sql connector?

Thanks!

Comment: What ever you're trying to do, you're probably doing it wrong. Disabling EF's internal transaction would leave the EF internal code in an unknown state after an operation. Just don't do it.

Instead describe the problem you're trying to address. EF is best used by declaring a new context for each unit of work. A unit of work should consist of a minimum number of operations that would still leave the business data in a logically correct state if rolled back. Creating an order can be a separate unit of work from adding line items to the order. This works best with an MVVM architecture.

Comment: @Kurian, You are right about the unknown state, so I wouldn't do this for all EF connections. We however have lots of events that do a single insert each, and each of these have the addition performance overhead of a transaction that they don't need.

Comment: I can blindly state that database operations are NOT a bottleneck in what ever you're doing. It's THAT unlikely. In fact, every insert statement SHOULD be in a transaction with appropriate locking on whatever tables it's reading & writing etc. A DBMS is designed for this. There are all kinds of implicit transactions and locking taking place for every statement you execute. The EF transaction is negligible. If performance is lacking, you have a code quality issue.

Comment: @Kurian, I suspect you are right. However we have a tracing tool showing something like 5ms for the BEGIN statement and then 15ms for the actual sql. So it might be possible that taking out the BEGIN will make the sql run for 20ms, however I can't try this without turning off the internal transaction in EF....

Comment: Think of it this way: Every statement is executed in a transaction of sorts. Explicitly declaring the transaction simply enables you to move the end point to cover multiple lines. Every single line statement has implicit transactions and locks. The delay is more likely client side. EF is heavy and every operation is slow. The explicit transaction may be slowing down the EF code, but not the database engine. It is better to move some things into plain SQL statements which you execute through the context.

Comment: @Kurian what about the added time for the extra network traffic and handshaking? BTW I really appreciate your input on this, it has given me food for thought.

Comment: With connection pooling it's again negligible. The program should NOT be blocking assuming a low network latency. What if the link is over the Internet with 300ms latency instead of a LAN?

Answer (score 0):

EF5 is hard-coded to wrap INSERTS and UPDATES into transactions. And in almost all cases, this is the desired behavior when batching writes of multiple entities.

If you want to change that you will have to write new code for yourself, compile it to an appropriate DLL, and reference the new code instead. A lot of work to get around a very important safety feature. I don't recommend it.

The question is why do you want to disable transactions so much?

Is it causing performance problems? Do you find the extra safety of the transaction to be detrimental to the business process?

It sounds like you don't care if writes are lost, phantom reads, etc. happen (which I assume because you are wanting to skip transactions all together), which is a bad idea.

If that's not the case (I hope) and you're worried about performance, maybe your transaction level isolation is too high for what you want? You may want to wrap your other calls in transactions that set a much lower (less safe, but less locking so better performance) isolation level like READ UNCOMMITTED?

Comment: Thanks Jon, this was a while ago. From memory my issue was slow write performance and me misinterpreting the time my tracing tool was attributing to the BEGIN and END statements. IIRC we ended up going for a microORM solution that allowed us to write stuff like UPDATE WHERE statements which improved performance exponentially